# PHP timestamp convert to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp

Hello friends this my my php code.

```
<?php
   $date3=date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
   echo $abc3=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
   $t3= strtotime($abc3) * 1000;
?>
```

print date is `2014-01-23 08:43:45`

Friends This is my Javascript Code

```
<script>
 var t3=<?php echo $t3; ?>;
function update_clock3(){

var now = new Date(Number(t3));

var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var seconds = now.getSeconds();   

alert(hours +":"+ minutes + ":" + seconds); 

}
</script>
```

The Javascript code is print date is the wrong.

javascript output is under.

13:13:45

please help where i doing mistake.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert client time to server time zone. Use `Date.prototype.getUTCHours`  and etc methods. Also you can use `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()` to check the time zone difference and notify use if day changed, for example:

```
<script>

    var t3=<?php echo $t3; ?>;
    function update_clock3(){

        var now = new Date(Number(t3));
        var year = now.getUTCFullYear();
        var month = now.getUTCMonth();
        var day = now.getUTCDate();
        var hours = now.getUTCHours();
        var minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
        var seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();  
        //local zone - UTC zone, so +1 UTC will be -60
        var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
        //convert hours from UTC time zone to local
        var minutesOffset = offset % 1;
        var localHours = hours - Math.floor(offset);
        var localMinutes = minutes - minutesOffset * 60; 
        var localDate = new Date(year,month, day, localHours, localMinutes, seconds);

        //day can be change by adding offset
        if (localDate.getDate() !== day) {
            alert("You have another day");
        }

        alert("UTC time:" + hours +":"+ minutes + ":" + seconds); 

    }
</script>
```

Comment: hey pinal please can you tyr on this time zone. 'Asia/Hong_Kong'

Comment: i got on this timzone vary long different on hourse.

Comment: I edit my answer, add time zone check  and remove `Europe/Paris` hardcode.

Answer (score -1):

use below:-

```
<script>
var t3 = '<?php echo $t3; ?>';

function update_clock3(){

    var now = new Date(t3);

    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();   

    alert(hours +":"+ minutes + ":" + seconds); 

}
</script>
```

**EDIT:-**

```
<?php
   $date3=date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
   echo $abc3=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
   $t3= strtotime($abc3) * 1000;
?>

<script>
var t3 = '<?php echo $t3; ?>';
alert(t3);

</script>
```

Comment: @renishkhunt do You want 2014-01-23 08:43:45 output from Your javascript?

Comment: @renishkhunt then check my edited code. and why are You trying to use Date() function? try above. it'll alert something like 1390463898000.

Answer (score -1):

Pass the date string directly inside the date function

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to display the hour of the time right now.</p>

<button onclick=" update_clock3()">Try it</button>

<script>

 var t3='2014-01-23 08:43:45';
function update_clock3(){

var now = new Date(t3);

var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var seconds = now.getSeconds();   

alert(hours +":"+ minutes + ":" + seconds); 

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in t3 is not a string date is a timestamp like 1390463898000

Comment: "print date is 2014-01-23 08:43:45 " why you mentioned like this. the above answer will work for this date string