# How to convert timestamp into unix timestamp in php?

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have set Geo-location plugin in my app. I have got time-stamp in this format ..1479279473848. Now i want to convert it to UNIX time-stamp something like 1479263460

Kindly suggest how to convert it into UNIX time-stamp.

Thanks

Comment: just divide it by 1000

Comment: the first step would be figuring out what the format of your time stamp actually *is*. the second step then is obvious. (both of which are demonstrated by pradyuts comment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP timestamp convert to javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302224/php-timestamp-convert-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be in milliseconds. Just divide it with 1000.

```
$timestamp = 1479279473848 / 1000;
```

This gives you a unix timestamp for the date: 2016-11-16 07:57:53